# Objective-C - allocation/initialization of an object with ARC

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I was wondering if I can directly alloc, init an ivar now with ARC (Because if I remember well it wasn't possible without ARC because it would leak memory no) ?

Example (consider an ivar declared like this) :

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *myArray;

@synthetize myArray = _myArray;
```

And then do

```
self.myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:object1, object2, nil]; //I know I could directly use [NSArray arrayWithObjects:...] but that's the purpose of my question
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

The only difference between using `alloc`/`initWithObjects:` and `arrayWithObjects:` is that the former leaves you with a retained object, while the second doesn't. If for some reason you wanted to use the former to initialize a property, you'd want to add a call to `autorelease` to avoid a leak. So you'd do this:

```
self.myArray = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:foo, bar, nil] autorelease];
```

You're correct that with ARC, the compiler will take care of adding that for you, so you can now just say:

```
self.myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:foo, bar, nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

It would, if you didn't release it on your `dealloc` method. With ARC you are responsible for the allocation. In the `dealloc` method, using ARC, you can still release resources using `self.ivar=nil` (but ARC is already doing that automatically for you), but not using the word `release` explicit. Also, ARC does not allow you to call `[super dealloc]`.

Answer (score -1):

You can still alloc and retain. The object lifecycle remains the same, i.e. objects get release when reatin count drops to 0. All that ARC does for you is place the objects in an autorelease pool and correctly release it, where you should have done. You can still override dealloc.

You can find good article about ARC [here](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/11/everything-know-about-arc/#myth-no-memory-management-control)

Comment: This is incorrect. You can of course use `alloc` in ARC code, but not `retain`, `release`, or `autorelease`. Also, ARC does more than just putting everything in an autorelease pool; it analyzes your code to determine the lifetime of each reference and inserts appropriate calls to the memory management methods.

Comment: agree that retain cannot be used, but I have mentioned that lifecycle remains the same . read 2nd and 3rd line

Comment: Yes, but you first wrote: "You can still alloc and retain." Read 1st line. And as I pointed out, the sentence starting "All that ARC does..." is at best misleading.

Comment: I appreciate your observation, so I have upVoted your comment